# Why does function return bool when it is defined as an int?

Tags: c++, boolean, implicit-conversion, integer-promotion

Why does the `int hum2()` function returning a boolean type? Shouldn't the function return the type I defined it as. Like Float function returns float value of Double function returns a double value.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int hum2()
{
    return true;
}
bool hum(){

    return false;
}



int main()
{

    printf("%d\n",hum2());
    printf("%d\n",hum());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Automatic type promotion. Bool converts to int

Comment: What makes you think that it does return boolean?

Comment: The answer depends on the language you are using, because C did not initially know about boolean or `bool`. So please pick the language you want an answer for and do not tag the other one. I assume that you ask about C++ and not C, because the shown code does compile as C++ but not as C. E.g. here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php and here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php

Comment: @Efty Shan Abid This is not a C program.

Comment: Yes sorry for the confusion this is a c++ program

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you think `hum2` is returning a boolean type here? It's clearly returning an `int`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify which language you are using. (Pick one. If it's C++, my recommendation is to use C++ IO facilities, i.e. iostreams).

Comment: In C++ with cout etc you can have it print out the bool if you turn on the boolalpha option https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha

Comment: You confirm that this is not a C program, that it is a C++ program. But you do keep the C tag. You will have to explain which part of your question is C.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: Sorry, misread the history.

Answer (score 1):

For starters to make the program a correct C program you need to include the header `stdbool.h`.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

In this header `true` and `false` are macros that expand to integer constants correspondingly `1` and `0`.

And the macro `bool` expands to the integer type `_Bool`.

So there is neither conversion takes place in your program except in the call of `printf` where an object of the type `_Bool` is promoted to the type `int`.

In C++ the boolean literals `true` and `false` are converted to values of the return type of the first function. The literal `true` is converted to the integer value `1` and the literal `false` is converted to the integer value `0`.

From the C++ 14 Standard (4.5 Integral promotions)

> 6 A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int,
> with false becoming zero and true becoming one.

Thus either your program is compiled using a C compiler or a C++ compiler in any case the functions returns integer values if the functions return type is `int`.

Comment: One complement : in C, 0  is false, any other value is true.(eg: 42 is true)

Comment: @PtitXav Just like in C++, any value other than 0 is true including negative numbers.

Comment: @Ptitxav: It's quite a different topic. Vlad is speaking about what are results of converting boolean values `false` and `true` to the `int` type,  whilst your comment is  about what `int` values are converted to `false` and to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does function return bool when it is defined as an int?

Well, *why* it returns is because that's the way you wrote it, but I guess you're asking, how/why does this work?

And the answer is that for convenience, C is perfectly willing to perform a number of *implicit conversions* between values of different types.  This is usually a good thing, and once you get used to it, you'll appreciate it.

Let's look at the lines you were probably puzzled about.

```
int hum2()
{
    return true;
}
```

If function `hum2` is declared as returning `int`, how can you return this Boolean value from it?  Well, deep down, a Boolean is just a number, generally either 0 or 1.  So there's no problem returning that number as an `int`.  The compiler typically doesn't even warn you.  This is partly because, once upon a time, C did not even have a separate Boolean type, and everybody used `int` (or some other integer type) to store their 1/0 true/false values.

The situation here is kind of like declaring a function

```
double one()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Here function `one` is declared as returning type `double`, yet we return an `int`.  How does this work?  Well, again, the compiler is perfectly willing to perform an implicit conversion.

The other line you were probably puzzled about was this one:

```
printf("%d\n", hum());
```

Now, function `hum` was declared as returning `bool`, so how can you get away with printing it as a `%d`?  Don't the extra arguments you pass to `printf`, and the `%`-specifiers you use in the format string, have to match exactly?

Yes, they do have to match, but there are three additional factors.  First, there is no `%`-specifier for `bool`.  Second, there's also an additional set of rules that comes into play, because `printf` is special.  Third, since a Boolean value is actually just a number, 0 or 1, we will find that underneath, type `bool` is actually going to be implemented as an integer type, `int` or `short int` or `char`.

Since `printf` accepts a variable number of arguments, something called the *default argument promotions* come into play.  These say that every integer type smaller than `int` is automatically promoted to `int`, and also (though it doesn't matter here), that type `float` is promoted to `double`.  So function `hum`'s return value gets promoted from `bool` to `int`, and it's perfectly fine to print it with `%d`.

Answer (score -1):

Here, as you are using the integer specifier (`%d`) in `printf("%d\n", hum());` , the boolean value is implicitly getting casted to integer. Since with printf there is no special specifier for boolean, outputting `true` or `false` directly to console cannot be possible.

But you can use `std::cout` with `std::boolapha` flag to get the desired output

```cpp
std::cout << std::boolalpha << hum() << std::endl ;
```

or the not so good option with `printf("%s", hum() ?"true":"false");`

Comment: `%d` in `printf` does not cause a conversion of an argument to an integer. Also, there is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is an explicit operator (`(type)` in C or C++, and `static_cast<type>(expression)` and similar forms in C++) that performs a conversion. That makes it an explicit conversion. There are implicit conversions. `%d` does not cause an implicit conversion of any argument.